# How can I get exact UTC/GMT time on client side if client time is ahead or behind?

Tags: javascript, datetime

As per I know,

```
var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
```

It's based on client time machine.

Suppose, client machine has modified their time ahead or behind, then it will be a problem.

Please, correct me If I'm wrong.

**Question**
 - How can I get exact UTC/GMT time on client side if client time is ahead or behind?

Comment: `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` will give you the offset timezone in minutes. To make in to hours, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30377368/1577396)

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) function:

```
var utc = new Date().toISOString(); // 2015-05-26T04:30:09.490Z
```

Or create a new date by calculating the [timezone offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

```
var now = new Date();
var utc = new Date(now.getTime() + now.getTimezoneOffset() * (60 * 1000));
```

Note that in above code `getTimezoneOffset()` returns timezone in minutes. So, I am converting it in to milliseconds.

There is always [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone) library which simplifies dealing with timezones.

Comment: It's not working if I have set my time ahead, for ex. +2 hour. Then, var utc gave me wrong .

Comment: I'm not sure which of the 2 examples you are referring to. Also, by "my time ahead" you mean "timezone" right?

Comment: I mean same timezone but some hours ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution independent of a user's clock, you have to use a web service of some sort. You can build your own (send your server's time to the browser), or use a web service.

Here is an example using timeapi.org, which returns and outputs the current time in GMT. You can modify this code to send the user's timezone as an offset instead (replace URL with something like `http://www.timeapi.org/+10/now` where +10 is the offset).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myCallback(json) {
    alert(new Date(json.dateString));
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://timeapi.org/utc/now.json?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

Lifted from [this page](http://www.timeapi.org/).